# How to select specific column in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have to select specific column from my DataTable using linq
I am using this code

```
ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable().Where<DataRow>(r=>r.Field<int>("productID")==23).CopyToDataTable();
```

~

But it is giving me all columns and I need only PRODUCTNAME , DESCRIPTION  , PRICE

How I can write this query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To expand a bit on @lazyberezovsky, you can use an anonymous type projection to get all of the fields you want:

```
ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Where<DataRow>(r => r.Field<int>("productID") == 23)
    .Select(r => new { ProductName = r.Field<string>("productName"), 
                       Description = r.Field<string>("description"),
                       Price = r.Field<decimal>("price") });
```

I don't know what name and type your product name, description, and price fields are, so you will have to substitute those.

Comment: Thanks it works.You got my question claerly and your answer is the answer of my question. I know already how to show one field but don't know how to show 3

Answer (score 8):

Use Select method:

```
ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable()
           .Where<DataRow>(r=>r.Field<int>("productID")==23)
           .Select(r => r.Field<int>("productID"));
```

UPDATE: In case you need to select several columns, you can return anonymous type:

```
var query = from row in dt.ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<int>("productID")==23
            select new  {
                           ProductID = x.Field<string>("productID"),
                           Foo = x.Field<string>("foo")
                        };
```

If you need to copy that data to new table, you'll face problem (CopyToDataTable requires collection of DataRow objects). See [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) to solve this problem.

Comment: By this I can pick only one column but I have to pick 3